# Is it correct to use 'for' after 'walk'?

Tags: phrase-usage

I would like to know whether it is correct to use 'for' after 'walk' in this sentence.

> Everyday, we walk for 10 miles to the villages around our town.

Comment: That is one common way to express that idea in English. Another is to leave out *for* entirely. "We walk 10 miles to the villages ..." There are other possibilities, but you can't go wrong with these.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct but not required.

> We walk for ten miles
>
> We walk ten miles

have nearly the same meaning.  Slight difference in nuance, "walk for 10 miles" is more common when the distance is the purpose of the walk

> Walk for 10 miles to raise money for cancer research.

But "walk 10 miles" when you are describing a walk for some other purpose

> The car broke down and I had to walk ten miles to the nearest village.

Even so, you could remove "for" from the first and put it in the second and nobody would find it strange.